# How to remove the js comments in the html when compress the html file?

Tags: html, uglifyjs

There is some inline js code with some comments in my html file(I know it's not good to write inline js code in the html, but here I have to do so), and I'm using `html-minifier` to compress my whole html, but it can't remove the js comments. This will result in some errors when I use the template engine(e.g. `art-template`). I set the `minifyJS` to `true` when using `html-minifier`, but it seems no use.

What is the correct way to remove the inline js comments using `html-minifier`? Or is there any other tool that can meet my requirements? Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you have to have inline Javascript?  If you extracted it to its own file and tried again it would probably work just fine.

Comment: I didn't write logic-related inline js code in my html. It's just some config to the certain page.

Comment: So why can't it be extracted to its own JS file that is only used for that page?

Comment: There have already been too many pages. I can't afford to grab every inline js code one by one.

Comment: consolidate them all into one file and include that one file

Comment: I can't do it this way because there have already been too many page to extract the inline js code